# Loop through JSON array element in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON structure like :

```json
{
    listOfVal: [
        val1,
        val2,
        val3
    ]
    name: "app"
    id: "9209629"
}
```

I want to check if `listOfVal` has say `val2`. `val2` can be at any index.

This JSON is part of a response to an API call and I am using:

```javascript
var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
```

to hold the JSON data.

Comment: that JSON is not valid.

Comment: @TMcKeown He probably just left the `,` symbols off, if he is successfully able to parse it, it's irrelevant to the question itself. Those `val#`s should be in quotes though, as far as I can tell.

Comment: thanks for the edit. I copied JSON from a JSON viewer and it had some formatting elements which i should have removed. My Bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your JSON isn't valid. You're missing commas and quotes.

```
{
    "listOfVal": [
        val1,
        val2,
        val3
    ],
    "name": "app",
    "id": "9209629",
    ...
}
```

once you have `data`, iterate over it with a `for` loop. You could use `indexOf`, but that doesn't work in `IE < 9`

```
function isInJSON(data, value){
    for(var i=0; i<data.listOfVal.length; i++){
        if(data.listOfVal[i] === value){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This won't always work if your `val`s are arrays or objects. If they are, you could run `for` loops to compare them, or you could use `underscore.js`: `_.isEqual(obj1,obj2)`.

OP requested using `forEach`:

```
var value; //define what you're looking for
data.listOfVal.forEach(function(val,key){
    if(val === value){
        alert('MATCH FOUND: responseBody["' + String(key) + '"] = ' + String(value));
    }
});
```

Comment: You actually don't need to include quotes around the keys within javascript objects-- it's implied, so whatever you use as the key names will automatically be converted into strings.

Ah, good catch with indexOf... I always forget that nothing is compatible with IE < 9, even if it is specified in ECMAScript... hahaha

Comment: @Mercury You're right if the object was a javascript object, but JSON object have to have strings for keys. And yeah, compatibility for IE is always a cute joke haha

Comment: actually for(var i=0; i<data.listOfVal.length; i++) loop worked for me. Though i was looking for a solution like foreach. Is there a way to convert this into foreach as well for search by a value ?

Answer (score -2):

If after using JSON.parse you had an object like this:

```
data = {
    listOfVal: [ 
        val1, 
        val2, 
        val3 
    ],
    name: 'app',
    id: '9209629'
    ...
}
```

Then you can access listOfVal as if it were any other object, and use indexOf to try to reach val2.

```
data.listOfVal.indexOf(val2);
```

This will either return a non-negative integer index where val2 resides in the array, or it will return -1, indicating that val2 does not exist within your array.